# How to enable Syntax highlighting on intellij?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, syntax-highlighting

I started to use intellij to code in java recently, and the Syntax highlighting with colors is not working on all types of elements. I already tryed to use a new theme, to disable power saved mode, but nothing seens to work. can anybody help?

[image]

I want to see a theme with different colors for different types of elements like classes, anotations, methods, properties, params, variables and so on.

Comment: Just mark `src` directory as source code root. Right click > Mark directory as > ...

Comment: Try opening up the ‘demo’ folder in IDEA as the root of the project, rather than opening the `SpringBoot2Essencials` folder. Then, it should recognise the Gradle configuration and set the project up accordingly.

Comment: @Mimimishkin That is not the proper solution here (if anything the `src/main/java` should be marked as source root). The proper solution is to import the project as a Gradle project, then IntelliJ will detect the right source roots itself.

Answer (score 1):

You need to import/open the project as a Gradle project, then IntelliJ will configure itself appropriately.

For example, close your current project, use File > New > Project from Existing Sources..., browse to the directory, select the build.gradle file and click OK.